# Does MaaS 1.2 have a built-in tftp server?

Tags: 12.10, server, maas

I am trying MaaS 1.2 on 12.10. However as declared it conflicts with tftpd-hpa. My question is does it contain a built-in tftp? I tried to install tftpd-hpa on another node, but there is no pxelinx.cfg dir in /var/lib/tftpd. In 12.04 with MaaS 0.1 everything is ready, including tftp and cfgs. Moreover, nothing is mentioned on "http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html". Could anyone give some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the exact error message that you get when you try to install maas?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. MaaS can be installed without error. But I think running of it needs tftp.

Answer (score 0):

The new MaaS on Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't need tftp server. It uses a python/twisted based tftp server, which I believe is far more efficient. Hence, you don't need to install anything else. And it doesn't need configuration as well.

The tftp related files are stored in /var/lib/maas/tftp folder.

And the kernel option changes if required, can be done in kernel_opts.py file found in
/usr/share/pyshared/provisioningserver/ folder.

Hope you find this useful.